# Integration of Five9, Workbook.net (CRM) and Etrique(Marketing Automation)

Tags: api, crm, saas

I am willing to know if these three software could be integrated to each other or not.

1. Five9 (Cloud Contact Center)

   > http://www.five9.com/
2. Etrique(Marketing Automation)

   > http://www.etrigue.com/
3. Workbook.net (CRM)

   > http://www.workbook.net/

If possible please post the links for useful information. API docs or screenshot or videos anything would help.